# Rate limiting Airbrake Javascript logs

Tags: airbrake, exception-notifier

I have followed the instructions available at https://github.com/airbrake/airbrake-js to allow for JS exceptions to be farmed out to Airbrake.

What I am wondering is - is there a way to intercept these exceptions BEFORE that are sent to Airbrake? I want to limit messages sent over the wire to Airbrake as it's not looking to good in the console when we start getting MANY 503 responses with the old message of "You've performed too many requests"

Answer (score 0):

We're currently re-writing our Javascript notifier. This will be one of the features of the updated notifier. Watch this space.

Ben

Comment: Would be possible to get an ETA to help us with our decision making?